# Getting 'ELF' when i printf scanner.source

Tags: c, file, crafting-interpreters

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I want to write the text into the scanner.source pointer

But when I print scanner.source I get 'ELF'. I don't know what is causing this.

Edit
Listed below the main file and the commands I ran

main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage Jlox Script");
        return 64;
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        runFile(argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        runPrompt();
    }
}
```

runFile Function

```
void runFile(char *path)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("file: not found");
        exit(65);
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fileSize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    scanner.source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (fileSize + 1));
    if(scanner.source == NULL){
        printf("error occurred allocating memory");
        fclose(file);
        exit(64);
    }
    size_t readFile = fread(scanner.source, sizeof(char), fileSize, file);
    fclose(file);
    if (readFile != fileSize)
    {
        printf("file closing here");
        fclose(file);
        exit(65);
    }
    scanner.source[fileSize] = '\0';
    printf("scanner source '%s'", scanner.source);
    run();
    if (hadError)
        exit(65);
}
```

text.txt

```
1 ()
2 **
3 ()
4 {};;
```

script ran

```
gcc -g  modifiedlox.c -o modifiedlox

./modifiedlox.text.txt
```

Comment: My first guess would be that you're reading a different file than you think you're reading. Probably an ELF executable. But we can't know unless you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I included the text file in it, in main I just call the runFile with the text file

Comment: You forgot to include `main` and everything else that is needed to compile. Also in what folder do you call that program and in what folder is the input file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in comments:

> in main I just call the runFile with the text file

But in fact no, that's *not* what the `main()` function later added to the question does.  It passes `argv[0]` to `runFile()`, and `argv[0]` is normally the name of the executable itself, as given on the command line.  And on your platform, that is indeed an ELF executable, as I speculated.

If you want to forward the program's first command-line argument to function `runFile()`, then that would be `argv[1]`.

---

Incidentally, this sort of thing is exactly why we ask those who pose debugging questions to present a minimal, reproducible example.  Although I'm a pretty good guesser, no one could answer this question with confidence until you presented a full enough picture of what the program was really doing.

Comment: yes! You are correct, gosh I didn't even notice the main file, I was so focused on thinking it was a pointer issue. I understand and I'm really sorry.
Thank you for your patience and help.